# Appended link to Autocomplete causing problems

Tags: jquery-ui, binding, autocomplete

Using the 'open' event I have appended an `<li>` which serves as a "See More Results" link at the bottom of the results. However any attempt I make to bind a click event is fruitless. I get an error in the jQuery UI saying "d.item is null" ln 242.

I think this means it is trying to look for data from the result query to automatically bind (like the other items) to it but it can't find anything. I punched the duck and used ._renderItem, does anyone know how to remedy this?

```
$('#q').t11e_single_autocomplete({
      ...
      'select': function(e, ui) {document.location=ui.item.url;},
      'open': function(e, ui) {$('.ui-autocomplete').append('<li class="bottom ui-menu-item"><a href="#" id="see-more-results" item="1">> See All Results</a></li>');}
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {...}
```

Thanks!